# Tails OS on one USB drive, but save downloaded files to second USB or SD drive

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, onion-routing, flash

If two USB drives are connected to a Windows notebook, one containing the Tails OS, are there any security loopholes or anonymity breaches by downloading files from .onion sites to the second USB drive? Are there any give-aways during transmission.

How about SD cards instead of USB drives for saving files?

Is the separate USB/SD safer than saving files directly to the notebook's hard drive, whether or not it's encrypted? Is the usage of encrypted USBs or SDs any better?

Answer (score 0):

> are there any security loopholes or anonymity breaches by downloading files from .onion sites to the second USB drive? Are there any give-aways during transmission.

Even if Tails [can't protect against compromised hardware](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html#compromised_hardware), the internal Harddrive is not accessible from Tails by default, so an eventual attacker should not be able to make a copy of your data when transmitting to the second USB stick.

> Is the usage of encrypted USBs or SDs any better?

Definitively. Tails [comes with everything you need](https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/encrypted_volumes/index.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all - remember, that Tails *is* Linux by heart, so - basically - there's an attack vector for gaining access to all the hard drives attached. If you want true anonymity - unplug it when you're using Tails : physically or via BIOS. Where to save data - it's totally up to you: Tails is Linux, so just mount it and use it